# How to stop VirtualBox from creating Host-Only Ethernet Adapters?

Tags: windows-10, networking, virtualbox, ethernet

On Windows 10 I am using an Ubuntu VirtualBox, and from time to time (maybe after a restart of windows 10?) probably the VirtualBox or Windows is creating Host-Only Ethernet Adapters:

[image]

This always disturbs the network I have set up and everytime I have to go to "Open Network & Internet settings" -> "Change Adapter options" to disable this unused adapter. And from time to time I have to open the "Device Manager" to remove all these useless adaptors.

Is there a way to prevent VirtualBox/Windows from spawning these annoying adaptors in the first place?

Comment: You should be able to remove these adapters from VirtualBox settings.

Comment: Also perhaps reinstall Virtual Box.  It should not make host only adapters randomly.,

Comment: @DanielB How can I set this?

Comment: I don't know how to stop them from spawning, but I may be able to come up with a PowerShell script to remove them all. Would that help?

Comment: @harrymc They would still end up getting remade; other OSs will probably use ports that are already in use by the current machine, and so while you maybe could delete the interfaces when they are not in use, this might result in an ip change every time, which could get annoying, but is survivable. However, simply telling virtualbox not to spawn them would probably result in some big problems.

Comment: why is it a problem that there is one?

Comment: Have you disabled it via "Enable Network Adapter" in *File > Host Network Manager* (see [screenshots](https://linuxhint.com/how-to-use-virtualbox-host-only-networking/))?

Comment: @harrymc Under "Tools" -> "Network Manager" no "Host-only Network" seems to be configured...

Comment: @harrymc A powershell script would certainly simplify things, even if I run it manually when needed...

Answer (score 1):

To remove one VirtualBox Host-Only adapter under Windows,
you may use the Microsoft utility of
[Windows Device Console (Devcon.exe)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon)
to enable and disable drivers, and may create icons for these commands on the
desktop.

This utility is part of the Windows Driver Kit, Visual Studio, or the
Windows SDK for desktop apps, but can be downloaded from
[DevCon-Installer](https://github.com/Drawbackz/DevCon-Installer).

Here is an (untested!) PowerShell script for removing all such virtual
network adapters that I found on Github
[Remove-VirtualBoxHostOnlyNetworkInterfaces.ps1](https://gist.github.com/rgl/ed3352d676a68e259e38cd2d3bce0049):

```
$devcon = "path-to-devcon.exe"

Get-NetAdapter `
    | Where-Object {$_.Virtual} `
    | Where-Object {$_.DriverFileName -like 'VBox*.sys'} `
    | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Removing the $($_.InterfaceAlias) interface..."
        $result = &$devcon remove "@$($_.PnPDeviceID)"
        if (!($result -eq '1 device(s) were removed.')) {
            throw "failed to remove the network interface $($_.InterfaceAlias): $result"
        }
    }
```